# Getting error in api calling in retrofit 1.9.0

Tags: java, android, retrofit

**My api call is like this**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/dealer/index.php")
    void getDealersPacks(
            @Query("r") String query,
            @Field("cd_dealer_id")
                    String cd_dealer_id,
            @Field("country_code")
                    String country_code,
            @Field("business_type")
                    String business_type, Callback<String> cb);
```

**And i am getting this error**

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_STRING but was OBJECT at line 1 column 59 path $.
```

Comment: @vineet share your response model and response from api....so that we can help......you are not handling response properly.

Comment: in postman i am getting this responce   {"success":true,"message":"","data":}

Comment: show your response model class

Answer (score 1):

The error says the method "getDealersPacks" is expecting a string value. But what you are sending as a parameter is an Object. So it is throwing syntax exception. Please properly check the data type of input params that you are sending.

Comment: i am sending all three parameters in string format

Comment: What is this "Callback<String> cb" ? Last parameter?? Better you check with your backend and confirm the parameters to be send for this api call.

Comment: this is a call back to handle success or failure result

Comment: Are you posting that call back param in postman.?

Comment: Try adding the callback as the method return type. Eg:-Call<String> searchUserName(@Query("userName") String userName);